# Detecting and Publishing Changes to Data in SQL Server in Real-time

Tags: sql-server, triggers, service-broker

I have an ERP System (Navision) where product data and stock numbers are frequently updated. Every time an attribute of a product is updated I want this change to be pushed to another SQL Server using Service Broker. I was considering using triggers for the detection, but I am unsure if that is the best way, and whether this is scalable. I expect updates to happen approx. once per second, but this number might double or triple.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Is _Always On Availability Groups_ an option? Is the target an exact copy or is there some transformation going on? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups

Comment: Hi Bjoern, I know you specifically mentioned Service Broker, but is this your only option? We had a similar requirement some years ago and at the end we decided to use Replication instead. This was a far quicker way to implement. There are some drawbacks: if you import a fob with database changes, you need to temporarily delete the tables from the publication. Moreover, you need to set the agent interval to fast polling to simulate a real time behaviour.

Comment: Would highly recommend consulting with your NAV partner on this. Most of the time this situation would be done through C\AL or a program designed to interface and integrate with NAV. If someone gives you an answer, and they don't know NAV, you should be highly critical of it. As they will not know any of your customizations or business logic beforehand.

Comment: It is not an exact copy of data. An example could be a product being ordered for delivery three weeks from now. This would create a change in the DB "Order" table, which affects the available stock. I would trigger off the order entering the table, and push the productid and quantity to another SQL Server via SQL Service Broker. On that other server I would have a windows service pull messages off Service Broker and update our product stock cache using a REST service. I don't want to use replication/polling if I can avoid it. And Jacob H, yes, thanks, I'll consult with our NAV partner for sure

Comment: The product stock cache is another platform, like SOLR or Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column for Last Modified Date for each record and update this column using the trigger each time a record is being updated. Then Run a scheduled job at a specific time each day (Off-business hours preferred) So that all records that are updated after the last scheduled run is processed.

So The following items need to be done

1. Add a new column LastModifiedDate in the table with DATETIME data type.
2. Create a Trigger to update the ModifiedDate each time the record is updated
3. Create a new table to store the schedule run date and time
4. Create a scheduled job on Database that will run at a specified time every day.
5. This job will pick all the records that have the value greater than the date in the Table Create on Step#4.

So Since only 1 column is being updated in the trigger, it won't affect the performance of the table. Also since we are running the update job only once a day, It will also reduce the Database Traffic.

Comment: Like Jacob H says, it needs to be real-time.

Comment: Yes, But it's just one option and we can choose any interval depending on our needs.